# How to get the Http Status Code from NoHttpResponseException in Android?

Tags: android, http-status-codes, apache-commons-httpclient

In Android i have an HttpClient that perform a GET on a webservice.
The webservice can return the Http Error 429 (too many requests) with a JSON detailed object of the error containing a some more data (eg. the time in the future at wich the request can be re-sent again).

Unfortunately the

```
response = httpclient.execute(httpGet, localContext);
```

raise a NoHttpResponseException and the response object remain NULL.

So i have no chanches to manage that specific 429 error.

Is there a solution?

**Update:**
I checked with fiddler that, when the server return the correct JSON object with HTTP Status code=429, httpclient.execute(httpGet, localContext); just throw NoHttpResponseException - so the problem isn't that the server don't return any result.

Comment: nohttpresponse tends to indicate there is no http response, hence no code.

Comment: @njzk2 I checked with fiddler that, when the server return the correct JSON object with HTTP Status code=429, httpclient.execute(httpGet, localContext); just throw NoHttpResponseException - so the problem isn't that the server don't return any result.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
WebRequestResult result = new WebRequestResult();
URL url = new URL(this.url);
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
HttpURLConnection  httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
//This here?
result.setStatusCode(httpConnection.getResponseCode());
result.setStatusDescription(httpConnection.getResponseMessage());
```

Comment: No. you haven't got the point.
My Server return a correct JSON object with http status code 429, on the android client app, the http error is threated like a NoHttpResponseException ...

Comment: actually, there may be something here. it is a different http client, and may have a different handling of exotic codes (like 429)

Comment: @Alex yeh you may be rigth that this solution is nothing for you.. you can only use this if you use gson. and with gson you can handle the different status code. and i would also recommend you to use gson. it is much simpler and easyer than the "original" JSONObjects and co.

Comment: @Mr.S Actually i already use GSON (if you mean this: http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)  i use JSON to convert JSON result to Java objects... but i can't understand how this can solve my problem. Are you suggesting me to make the server return ever a JSON object with HTTP status 200 also when it should return an error?

Comment: @Alex No the server can return a json object with an status 429, but the app can handle it throught the response code (in you case 429) and won't give you always an NoHttpResponseException.if you give me your email, i can send you a little testproject in which this handling should be solved!

Comment: @Mr.S how can i send you my email address without writing it here in public? it seems StackEx. network won't never implement a feature to contact directly users.

Comment: @Alex that's a good point... but I think the poeple here on stackoverflow are serius enought so they wont just write you withou any reason (also called spam ;-))

Comment: @Mr.S mmmh, the problem are the spammers, not the users of this network. Well, try to send me something here: eqfzfmys@sharklasers.com it's a temporary email that will last 60 minutes from now 9.16am utc.